# How can I differentiate an user from a workflow while in an ItemUpdating Event

Tags: 2010, development, workflow, event-receivers

Is there a way to differentiate an user from a workflow while in an ItemUpdating Event?

To show the my problem here's the ItemUpdating method:

```
    public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            int wfValue = int.Parse(properties.ListItem["ActiveWorkflow"].ToString());

            if (wfValue == 0 || wfValue == 1)
            {
                base.ItemUpdating(properties);
            }
            else
            {
                properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                properties.ErrorMessage = string.Format("Workflow {0} active.", wfValue);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
            properties.ErrorMessage = string.Format("Error: \n{0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

My problem is that Workflows trigger this events too and I want them not to be blocked by this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your workflow runs with system account then you can check the current user in the event receiver is it the system account (event fired by the workflow) or not (event fired by a user).

```
SPUser currentUser = properties.Web.CurrentUser;
SPUserToken sysAccountToken = properties.Web.Site.GetSystemToken();
if (currentUser.UserToken.CompareUser(sysAccountToken) == false)
{
    //your code to handle edits by users goes here
}
```

If the workflows run with the initiator's account (declarative workflows) then this will not work.

For 2013 you could use [SPItemEventProperties.IsBackgroundSave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.isbackgroundsave.aspx) but unfortunately that's not available in 2010.

Another workaround that would require more work is to create a custom Edit form and in the code behind set a property. Then in the event receiver you could check that property so you know has the Edit form (users) fired the event or not.